# Sort arraylist containing by object

Tags: java

i have `ArrayList` contains object named as `AccountProductCode` it has three parameter which is like for e.g.

```
  AccountProductCode accprocode = new AccountProductCode(); 
  accprocode.setAPPART("002");
  accprocode.setAPCODE("PC1");
  finalList.add(accprocode);
```

so here suppose list contain data like

```
APPART APCODE
001     PC1
002     PC2
003     PC3
004     PC4
*AL     PC1
```

i need to sort data like if `APART *AL` has same `APCODE` which is like other `APART` then i need exclude that `APCODE`. so the list will be like

```
APCODE
PC1
PC2
PC3
PC4
```

how can i do the program using `ArrayList` don't use `Set`..

and list should be sorted...

kindly check my new exact statment....Builds and returns a List object will all AccountProductCode objects for the participantID and participant ID *AL. If a product code exists for participantID and *AL, exclude the product code for *AL. The list should be sorted by the product code value.

Thanks
Vinod

Comment: You are not sorting, you are filtering out duplicates. Why can you not use a `Set` for it? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y it's not for duplicate if *AL has same APAPRT whihc is like other then i need to remove from the list it's only for *AL

Comment: @Space, probably because it's homework, and the requirement is to sort(?)

Comment: @Space check my new description wht i want

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply write a new arraylist with the filtered data:

```
List<AccountProductCode> filtered = new ArrayList<AccountProductCode>();
Set<String> apcodes = new HashSet<String>();
for (AccountProductCode code:getList()) {   // some magic to get the current list
  String apcode = code.getApCode();
  if (apcode.equals("*AL") && apcodes.contains(apcode)) {
     // skip duplicates
     continue;
  } else {
     apcodes.add(apcode);
     filtered.add(code);
  }
}
```

The filtered list is free of duplicates (according to your custom rule).

Comment: @vinod - you didn't tell. That sounded like some example. - improved version limits the filtering to those `*AL` entries with already stored apcodes.

Comment: @vinod - I'm out - you're changing requirements far too often, now you want it filtered *and* sorted ;) Sean already showed you a good implementation to sort a (filtered) array.

Answer (score 2):

**Rewrite:** Now I'm no longer using an external set or map. The price for this is that I have to potentially iterate over the entire list for every add (horrible performance):

Add items like this:

```
public boolean addUniqueItem(List<AccountProductCode> list,
                             AccountProductCode item){
    for(AccountProductCode existingItem : list){
        if(item.getApart().equals(existingItem.getApart())return false;
    }
    return list.add(item);
}
```

Then sort the list like this:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<AccountProductCode>(){
    public int compare(AccountProductCode a, AccountProductCode b){
        return a.getApCode().compareTo(b.apCode());
    }
});
```

Comment: but where your comparing with *AL

Comment: @vinod `if(!map.containsKey(item.getAppart())){` here

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be in your object `AccountProductCode` add a `compareTo` method, so when you try to sort, it will use the `compareTo`, you can add some logic there if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Set`.  If you are unwilling to use a set:

1. sort by `APCODE`.
2. iterate over the list looking at each `APCODE` and filtering unwanted items.
3. if desired, sort by `APPART`.